# Cannot convert fom enum to interface it implements

Tags: java, enums

I'm in `Java 7` and I have the following enum:

```
public enum BooleanEnum implements StringRepresentable{
    YES {
        @Override
        public String getStringRepresentation() {
            return "true";
        }
    },
    NO {
        @Override
        public String getStringRepresentation() {
            return "false";
        }
    };
    public abstract String getStringRepresentation();
}
```

Now I have the method:

```
List<StringRepresentable> getValues(){
    return Arrays.asList(BooleanEnum.values()); //Type mismatch: 
                  //cannot convert from List<BooleanEnum> to List<StringRepresentable>
}
```

What's wrong with that `enum`? It implements the interface, therefore the code should have compiled fine.

Comment: try `List<? extends StringRepresentable> getValues()...`

Comment: Shouldn't the List be `List<StringRepresentable>` instead of `List<StringRepresentation>`?

Comment: @Loki It was just a typo.

Comment: **[It's because List<BooleanEnum> is not a subclass of List<StringRepresentable>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745265/is-listdog-a-subclass-of-listanimal-why-arent-javas-generics-implicitly-p)**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> It implements the interface, therefore the code should have compiled fine.

No, because the type argument is being inferred as `BooleanEnum` - and a `List<BooleanEnum>` isn't a `List<StringRepresentation>`... you can add instances of *other* `StringRepresentation` implementations to the latter.

Four possible options:

- Specify that you're returning a list of some subclass of `StringRepresentation`:

  ```
  List<? extends StringRepresentation> get Values() {
      // Implementation as before
  }
  ```
- Specify the type argument:

  ```
  return Arrays.<StringRepresentation>asList(BooleanEnum.values());
  ```
- Use an intermediate variable for clarity:

  ```
  StringRepresentation[] array = BooleanEnum.values();
  return Arrays.asList(array);
  ```
- Don't return a `List<StringRepresentation>` at all; return an `Iterable<StringRepresentation>` at which point you can use `EnumSet` instead:

  ```
  Iterable<? extends StringRepresentable> getValues() {
      return EnumSet.allOf(BooleanEnum.class);
  }
  ```

Answer (score 2):

If this compiled, someone could do this:

```
List<StringRepresentation> values = getValues();
values.set(0, new SomeOtherStringRepresentation());
```

(since modifying the list returned by `Arrays.asList` modifies the original array) and then you'd have stored a `SomeOtherStringRepresentation` in the original array of `BooleanEnum`s! That's obviously not allowed.

Instead, you could make a copy, say as an `ArrayList`:

```
List<StringRepresentation> getValues(){
    return new ArrayList<StringRepresentation>(Arrays.asList(BooleanEnum.values()));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First `BooleanEnum.values()` returns an `BooleanEnum[]`, then with `Arrays.asList` you return a `List<BooleanEnum>`.

Since a `List<BooleanEnum>` is not a subset of `List<StringRepresentation>`, this code will not compile.

You could in theory get this code to compile by returning a `List<? extends StringRepresentation>`, however I would not recommend that as it is not really useful to the caller side.

Answer (score 2):

The type of your `List` is `StringRepresentation`, and `BooleanEnum` just implements `StringRepresentable`, an `interface` can't be converted into any types of `class` which implements the `interface`.

Answer (score 2):

You should return something like:

```
 return Arrays.<StringRepresentable>asList(BooleanEnum.values());
```

Since List of BooleanEnum is not  same as List of StringRepresentable.